# OpenGL - Create video output file

Tags: file, opengl, video, video-capture, glreadpixels

I want to be able to use OpenGL to create a video output file instead of the usual display on screen output. I am thinking by not using glutPostRedisplay() or (SFML version, which is something like this:) window.Display(), and somehow using glReadPixels() instead.

glReadPixels puts the pixel content into an array in memory (as you might already know) but how can I convert that into a frame, and string several frames together in a video file? And what format would the video file be in, so that I can play it?

I should explain why I want to do this: A lot of physics simulations can take a very long time to calculate enough information to display one frame, so it's better to leave it running overnight and play the video file the next morning. You wouldn't want to keep coming back every 5 minutes to see what had happened.

Comment: You can store it in raw frames (RGBA) and later process it eg. with gstreamer. (Which also allows a conversion pipeline to be embedded into an application).

Comment: So gstreamer is a something which I can include in my code and pass it some raw frames and I will get an ogg or mpeg or something output?

Comment: More or less. It a complete framework and as such can at least seem rather bloated for one application; but if one already knows eg. unix style pipes & filters, there's not that much learning curve.

Answer (score 4):

`glutPostRedisplay` is part of GLUT and not something specific to OpenGL.

You normally do offscreen rendering using either a PBuffer or using a hidden window and a framebuffer object.

Converting a image into a video can be done in various ways. For example you could utilize [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org) using `image2pipe` as input format and write the raw image data to the ffmpeg process standard input. A much simpler scheme would be to dump each frame into a separate image file. Using [libpng](http://www.libpng.org) is straightforward. You can then merge the individual images into a video.

However when doing physics simulation you should not dump the final rendering into a file. Instead you should store the simulation data for later playback, as you then can adjust rendering parameters without having to re-simulate everything. And you will have to make adjustments to the renderer!